# How do I get the value of a selected option an use it on an "if"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<select id="categories">
    <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
</select>
<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search here" autofocus>
```

And this jquery:

```
var categories = $("#categories option:selected").val();
var search = $("#search");

if (categories = "category2") {

    search.attr("placeholder", "Search for category 2");
} else {

    search.attr("placeholder", "Search for category 1");
}
```

I'm trying to put a different placeholder according to the selected value, but no matter what is selected, it always show the first placeholder. This might seem silly, but further I want to be able to pick the value of the selected option to make the search in that specific category, kinda like the Amazon website.

I have used `==` to compare, but nothing happens, the placeholder stays with "Search here".

PS: With this code running, using the console on Chrome, if I type and execute `categories` it will always show in the console `category2`, no matter which one is selected, but if I type and execute `$("#categories option:selected").val();`, then it will show the selected value. I tried to put this directly inside the `if` in the code, but returned the same problem. I also tried to replace the `else` for `if (categories = "category1")`, but then it was the same problem, but this time the placeholder showed was always the second one.

Comment: Use `==` to compare, not `=`! `=` is for assignment!

Comment: Looks like you need to wrap everything in a handler for a $('#categories') change event. As written, your code is grabbing the initially selected value on page load.

Comment: I have used == to compare, but nothing happens, the placeholder stays with "Search here"

Comment: I also have tried to use the `$("#categories").change([[$(this).val("category2")], function(){$("search").attr("placeholder", "Search for category 2");})` and, in the same code, `$("#categories").change([[$(this).val("category1")], function(){$("search").attr("placeholder", "Search for category 1");})`, but didn't work. It only changed once and the placeholder of the change was the one who stayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//you should add an onChange event,like this:
$("#categories").change(function(e){
   var categories = e.target.value;
   if (categories == "category2") {
    ...
   } else {
    ...
   }
})
```